# Fractal dimension of time series

Tags: time-series, fractal

What does fractal dimension values of 1.02 and 1.6 indicate?
How is fractional differencing related to fractal dimension?

Comment: Could you indicate *which* fractal dimension you are referring to?  [There are many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension#Examples).

Comment: I used the formula FD=2-H. where H is Hurst exponent that is calculated using R/S analysis

Comment: Your first question is likely answered [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent): "A value H in the range 0.5–1 indicates a time series with long-term positive autocorrelation, meaning both that a high value in the series will probably be followed by another high value and that the values a long time into the future will also tend to be high". For the second part, I am not familiar with the term "fractional differencing". Can you expand your question with more details? Please also include the information in your comment to whuber in the question body.

Comment: I am clear about Hurst exponent and its values. But I am not clear what does fractal dimension computation contribute to the series. Fractional differencing is differencing the time series with fractional value

Comment: @GeoMat22, here is a question on the definition of fractional differencing: ["Understanding fractional-differencing formula"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145641/understanding-fractional-differencing-formula).

Comment: @user6460588 it is my understanding that the fractal dimension contributes the same information as the Hurst exponent. So my quote could be read "A value of D in the range 1-1.5 indicates ...". (Using your formula D=2-H.)